# ¿Cómo compilar opencv 3.1 con qt en una máquina de 64 bits?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

Estoy compilando el código fuente de opencv 3.1 con cmake 3.6.0 y Visual Studio 2013 (elijo el compilador para 64 bits). Quiero hacerlo funcionar con CUDA 5.6.1 (ya instalado) y qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.1 (ya compilado) en una máquina de 64 bits.

Ya logré hacer el build sin qt. El cmake reconoce el qt, y se genera el *Solution* de Visual studio (OpenCV.sln) sin problema. Pero cuando hago el build de ALL BUILD me salta el siguiente error repetidas veces:

> window_QT.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   struct QMetaObject const ...

Quiero saber si alguien pudo hacerlo (¿cómo?) o alguna otra opción para compilar opencv con qt y con mi versión de CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa que no pueda poner comentarios, dado que mi respuesta no es la solución, sino una sugerencia a probar.

Intenta poner la carpeta de construcción en el mismo nivel donde tienes el código fuente, a mi esto me ha solucionado problemas de enlace con `QMetaObject`.